# Handle special character ( _ ) in Middleman

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, special-characters, middleman

Working on my very first project using Middleman 3.3.3 & ROR4. I have a page where I need to display locally saved images, and please note that I **CAN NOT** modify the file names.

Now the problem I am having is looks like middleman doesn't like file names with underscores ( _ ). Please forgive my limited knowledge, but looks like when I `build the site`, middleman adds some sorts of random numbers at  the end of the file and displays them. But the files with this special character ( _ ) are left as it is and thus not showing up on the site (locally they are working though).

**Here are 2 examples:**

`<img src="../img/youtube/B7NPBFZ1LB4-60b31c47.jpg">`...successfully adds the random number (-60b31c47) at the end of the name and displays the image

`<img src="../../img/youtube/_JvAkS3d9No.jpg">`...no random numbers are added, & doesn't display the image

I have all the image/video info in a **YML** file like this...

```
- tab_title: Blah blah blah...
  headline: Blah blah blah...
  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JvAkS3d9No'
  guid: '_JvAkS3d9No'
  caption: 'Underwater dogs'
```

I have also tried the followings ways without any success...

```
guid: "_JvAkS3d9No" 
guid: "&#95;JvAkS3d9No"
guid: '&#95;JvAkS3d9No'
```

Can anyone please help me solve this issue? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `image_tag` helper and `:asset_hash` configuration. Those 'random' numbers are likely generated hashes used for cache busting.

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/improving-cacheability/

http://middlemanapp.com/basics/helpers/